# Which could be the best Xpath to Get text when there is a text on both <td>

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I have the follow xml which I need to scrape:

```
<div class="tab_product_details">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>...</tr> 
      <tr>...</tr> 
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>
        <td> text 1 </tr>
        <td> text 2 </tr>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan = "2">
        <table>
          <tbody>
           <tr>
              <td> Adjustment</td> this text i do not need it!
              <td></td>
           </tr>           
           <tr class="feature">
              <td> text3</td> 
              <td> text4 </td>  
           </tr>
```

My actual xpath is the following:

text1 =response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"tab_product_details")]//td[followingsibling::td[not(table)]]')

text2 = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"tab_product_details")]//td[2]')

But I continue to get the texts that have no pair

Any help very welcome, thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get text *if both cells (`td`) are not empty* try

```
//div[@class = "tab_product_details"]//tr[count(./td[normalize-space()]) = 2]/td/text()[1]
//div[@class = "tab_product_details"]//tr[count(./td[normalize-space()]) = 2]/td/text()[2]
```

Comment: Thank you!! I need one xpath to get text "Shoes" and another xpath to get "Black"

Comment: thank you! it actually works but not as I wish, I jus edit my code html, do you still suggest same xpath? I need to get with one xpath text 1 and 3 and with another xpath 2 and 4 lets say for Attributes and Values...